# automatic type conversations in qml signal handler

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qtquick2

In a QtQuick 1.0 (Qt 4.8) application I had the following signal handler code.

```
Item {
  property bool landscape: false
  [...]
  Connections {
  [...]
    onPpar: {
      landscape = value;
      [...]
    }
  }
}
```

... where value comes from a signal raised by the C++ backend and contains indeed a string which is either 'true' or 'false'. This worked fine on my Qt4.8 application but the type conversation to the bool property stopped working when I ported the app to Qt5.1 and QtQuick 2.0. Now I have to write something like

```
onPpar: {
  landscape = (value == 'true');
}
```

... to get it running.

I thought the type conversation is part of what JavaScript does automatically? And as I said, until 4.8 it worked perfectly without the explicit conversation trick.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's a bug (or feature) in Declarative module in 4.8. Qt5 has a proper behaviour, because all strings "true", "false" and "trololo" will evaluate to Boolean true. Any non-empty string will evaluate to true. So the proper solution is to change the signal parameter from string to bool. If you cannot do that for some reason, then you need to write

```
landscape = (value == 'true');
```

as you do now.